# extjs message box customisation

Tags: extjs3

In the most basic form, the EXTJS prompt goes like this:

```
Ext.MessageBox.prompt('Name', 'Please enter your name:', showResultText);
});
```

Now in my application, there is a steylesheet that renders all the message boxes grey. And the buttons are also grey so the buttons are indistinguishable from the grey background of the prompt box. So is there a way to customize the prompt so that I can put  a border around the button Ok and Cancel? My other question is this: Is there  a way to put a help icon inside the prompt box? In MessageBox, there is a config option called ICON. Is there a way to use this option inside a prompt?

Answer (score 0):

**1) to add icon to prompt box :**

`Ext.MessageBox.prompt` is just a wrapper method to provide some default options to `Ext.MessageBox.show` so you can create a different wrapper method that will use your own options, and then you can easily override `Ext.MessageBox.prompt` with your custom prompt wrapper

```
var customPrompt = function(title, msg, fn, scope, multiline, value){
     Ext.MessageBox.show({
          title : title,
          msg : msg,
          buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
          fn: fn,
          minWidth: Ext.MessageBox.minPromptWidth,
          scope : scope,
          prompt:true,
          multiline: multiline,
          value: value,
          icon : Ext.MessageBox.QUESTION
     });
     return Ext.MessageBox;
};

customPrompt('title', 'message');
```

---

**2) to change styling of buttons  :**

Button elements are stored in the dialog component for reference so you can fetch those and add custom class to the buttons

```
var dlg =  Ext.MessageBox.getDialog();
var buttons = dlg.buttons;
for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
     buttons[i].addClass('custom-css-class');   // class that will do styling of buttons
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When we call customPrompt('title', 'message'); and do not pass in the other function params like fn,scope...etc...why is there no exception thrown by extjs?

Comment: that will simply be passed as undefined and `Ext.MessageBox.show` function will check for correct data and ignore undefineds